# Plain JavaScript prevent eventListener being executed twice

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been breaking my head on the following. In the [MDN Documentation on EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) the following is stated:

> Multiple identical event listeners
>
> If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same
> EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are
> discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and
> since the duplicates are discarded, they do not need to be removed
> manually with the removeEventListener method.

Which is a great thing. So I cannot add a duplicate `EventListener` on an element, but how do I find out if there is already an `EventListener` attached to *another* element somewhere in the DOM?

Say, I have an event called `expandNavigationGroup`, which is fired whenever my navigationpanel is clicked to open a navigationgroup. I can attach a listener for this event anywhere in my DOM. For instance:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("somediv");
el.addEventListener("expandNavigationGroup", doSomething, false);
```

The `doSomething` method does something relevant, like cleaning something up. It needs to be done once, but only once, when a navigationgroup is opened, but if my code does the following:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("someotherdiv");
el.addEventListener("expandNavigationGroup", doSomething, false);
```

The `EventListener` is added twice, and my cleanup code is executed twice.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hi Tuvokki, could you please add a jsfiddle with htis issue, so we can work from there?

Site: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

[@Chris is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803643/4386702). The only thing you could do is use some kind of "_.once" function.

Here's an implementation:

```
var once = (function (func) {
  var wasExecuted = false
  return function onceExecuter () {
    if(wasExecuted) {
      wasExecuted = true
      return func.apply(null, arguments)
    }
  }
})()
```

Now you can do this:

```
var doSomethingOnce = once(doSomething)
doSomething()
doSomething()
```

And `doSomething` is executed once

Comment: The question is not how to prevent the side-effects of the doSomething method being executed twice, but how to prevent double (or more) execution.

Comment: Maybe the question is not 100% clear. How to prevent the EventListener from being added twice and therefore my cleanup code being executed twice. What this prevents is not the EventListener being added twice, it mitigates the effect of it, it does not prevent it.

Comment: Sorry... I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(!wasExecuted) { ... }`? Seems like this logic would never run.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN Documentation If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the `same EventTarget` with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded.
You are registering event on different targets `somediv` and `someotherdiv` and hence the cleanup code is executed twice.

Comment: The question is: how to _prevent_ this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not registering the EventListeners on the same EventTarget you would have to remove the EventListeners manually.

```
var el = document.getElementById("somediv");
el.addEventListener("expandNavigationGroup", doSomething, false);
el.removeEventListener('expandNavigationGroup', doSomething, false);

var el = document.getElementById("someotherdiv");
el.addEventListener("expandNavigationGroup", doSomething, false);
el.removeEventListener('expandNavigationGroup', doSomething, false);
```